# Access Syntax Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, join, inner-join

I'm attempting to join multiple tables in my Access database.  I continue to receive a "syntax error".  Please let me know if you need more information.  I posted the schema below.

```
SELECT VicDescriptions.VID, 
       VicDescriptions.Make, 
       VicDescriptions.Vic_Year, 
       VicDescriptions.OptionTable, 
       VacDescriptions.Accessory, 
       VacValues.Value, 
       VacValues.ValueType
FROM  VicDescriptions 
       INNER JOIN VacValues 
         ON ( VicDescriptions.Vic_Make = VacValues.Vic_Make 
              AND VicDescriptions.Vic_Year = VacValues.Vic_Year )
     INNER JOIN VacDescriptions
         ON ( VacDescriptions.Period = VacValues.Period
               AND VacDescriptions.VAC = VacValues.VAC);
```

[DATABASE SCHEMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyoYd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access like parentheses for joins:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM (VicDescriptions INNER JOIN
      VacValues 
      ON VicDescriptions.Vic_Make = VacValues.Vic_Make AND
         VicDescriptions.Vic_Year = VacValues.Vic_Year
     ) INNER JOIN
     VacDescriptions
     ON VacDescriptions.Period = VacValues.Period AND
        VacDescriptions.VAC = VacValues.VAC
```